# Duplicate Spring Batch Job Instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-boot

I have a small sample Spring Batch application that when started for the first time will work fine but whenever I shut the application down & restart the jar I always get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Duplicate entry '1' for key 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 1
```

I'm not sure if I have the job incrementer setup wrong. But like I said I can start it up & then use the web service url, `/jobLauncher.html`, to invoke the batch process any number of times just fine. It's only after I shutdown the application & restart it that I get this error. It wants to use id 1 for the job execution table but id 1 is already there from the previous runs.

Main class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, new String[]{ "date=" + System.currentTimeMillis() });
    }
}
```

Webservice class

```
@Controller
public class JobLauncherController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
    @ResponseBody
    public String handle() throws Exception{
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", System.currentTimeMillis() + "").toJobParameters());
        return "Started the batch...";
    }
}
```

Spring Batch class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SampleBatchApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    protected Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                                        ChunkContext context) {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("job")
                   .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                   .flow(this.step1())
                   .end()
                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
        return this.steps.get("step1").tasklet(this.tasklet()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        try {
            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setUsername("test");
            ds.setPassword("test");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring-batch");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the issue.  When using the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation from Spring Boot it will invoke the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration` class which will initialize the database from the 'schema-mysql.sql' file.

Inside the [schema-mysql.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql) file is some code to reset the sequence id's for the batch meta tables which is why I was getting a duplicate key error:

```
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ values(0);
```

The fix was to build the Spring Batch tables separately & then change the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation to:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

so that when the application starts up it will not try to initialize the Spring Batch tables.

To exclude or customize Spring Boot's auto-configuration for other components you can find some docs here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-autoconfigure/README.html

The BatchAutoConfiguration code:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: When I did this, the batch job is just never run.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem and tried with above solution as well, but it didn't work. So I fixed it with a workaround.

While creating spring batch metadata-schema for the table **BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE** add **AUTO_INCREMENT** for the column **JOB_INSTANCE_ID** and it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the initial values in *seq tables with following query, you can also use 0 in place of 10.

```
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 10 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ);

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 10 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_JOB_SEQ);

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 10 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ);
```