# Duplication Job in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Getting error Cannot Register Job Configuration because DuplicationJobException After Upgrade to Spring 2.x

Already checked, there is no duplicate name in my code.

The Error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobCalcSampleDetail' defined in class path resource [id/co/a/microservice/batch/job/SampleJobConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Cannot register job configuration; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [jobCalcSampleDetail] was already registered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at id.co.a.microservice.batch.NcsBatchServiceApplication.main(NcsBatchServiceApplication.java:15)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Cannot register job configuration; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [jobCalcSampleDetail] was already registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [jobCalcSampleDetail] was already registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.register(MapJobRegistry.java:52)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.java:146)
    ... 24 more
```

Job Configuration Code

```
@Configuration 
@EnableBatchProcessing 
public class SampleJobConfiguration {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public PostgresDbConfig postgres;

@Value("${xxx.chunk.default}")
private int chunkSize;

@Value("${xxx.limit.retry}")
private int retryLimit;

@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet taskletRmvSample(@Value("#{jobParameters['period']}") String period,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['clearData']}") Boolean clearData) {
    return (StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
        if (clearData) {
            new JdbcTemplate(postgres.dataSource()).execute("");
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    };
}

@Bean
public Step step1RmvSample() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1RmvSampleDetail").tasklet(
            taskletRmvSample(null, null)).build();
}

@Bean
public Job jobCalcSampleDetail() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobCalcSampleDetail").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(
            step1RmvSample()).build();
}
}
```

Main Application Code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient 
@EnableScheduling
public class NcsBatchServiceApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(NcsBatchServiceApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Used Spring Boot Parent 2.1.4 - Spring Batch Core 4.1.1

previously it s working fine when using spring 1.5.17 but after upgrade to spring 2.* is error.

Also tried to add make modular but still error

```
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
```

Package Structure [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJhN8.png)

Maybe somebody can help.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like multiple Spring Batch Configuration. Hope this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597683/duplicate-spring-batch-job-instance

Comment: You should have two `jobCalcSampleDetail` jobs somewhere in your config. I see you said `Already checked, there is no duplicate name in my code`. In this case, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the issue and help you.

Comment: @MebinJoe when i do this, the job will not registrated.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i just have one, will provide you the package structure

Comment: Thanks for providing the package structure picture. However, this does not help. Spring Boot may scan your classpath and find another config class named `jobCalcSampleDetail`. `it s working fine when using spring 1.5.17 but after upgrade to spring 2.* is error.`: I can't see from what you shared what could be the cause of this regression. Please provide a MCVE so we can reproduce the issue and help you.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks for response. The Issue is solved, it happen because i implement ApplicationContextAware to other JobConfig, then it will register the Job as a bean twice. Because of that my job always get duplicateException

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had several jobs defined in different packages but if I created more than one job at a time (by toggling the @Configuration) the application threw a duplicateJobConfiguration Exception. After working through pretty much every solution presented by Google and StackOverflow I stumbled across my solution which was to remove from the class that included the Job bean a boilerplate post-processor that had been copied in from a code sample somewhere:

```
@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor edwJobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry 
 jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new 
     JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
 jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
 return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
}
```

Somehow the multiple instances of JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor were triggering the error even though each was given a unique name.

Comment: You are right ! Your reply saved me in understanding this error.

Comment: Saved my day, lol :) Thanks)