# Spring batch instance id duplicate key error, trying to start from #1

Tags: spring-batch

I am copying java code(using springboot spring batch) and database from dev server to local(desktop) and run it. Getting an error.

It works fine in Dev server. In local , spring-batch is resetting Job instance to 1 and causing primary key error.Is there any option in spring batch so that it starts with next instance id instead of 1? Please let me know

Referred to stackoverflow link below , seems related but posted few years back and reference links does not work anymore.
[Duplicate Spring Batch Job Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597683/duplicate-spring-batch-job-instance)

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Jobclass {
   #Rest of the code with Job Bean and steps which works fine in Dev server
}
```

Error:
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY 
    constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AFB5435C7'. Cannot insert duplicate key 
    in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (5).

Comment: `spring-batch is resetting Job instance to 1`: Spring Batch does not reset the id. Make sure the database schema is not created each time. How is your datasource configured? Are you instructing spring boot to always create the schema (through the `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property)?

Comment: I already tried spring.batch.initialize-schema=never , it is still same issue. As i am copying data from DEV server to local database , BATCH_JOB_* tables have data from jobs ran in DEV. For some reasons in local spring batch is starting SEQUENCE from 1 to determine JOB_INSTANCE_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Batch table instance and execution not updated with proper key , so manually what I have done is created table and added first row, this will not throw any duplicate and primary key issue.*

```
drop table batch_job_seq;
drop table batch_step_execution_context;
drop table batch_step_execution_seq;
drop table batch_step_execution;
drop table batch_job_execution_seq;
drop table batch_job_execution_params;
drop table batch_job_execution_context;
drop table batch_job_execution;
drop table batch_job_instance;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_instance` (
  `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VERSION` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `JOB_KEY` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `JOB_INST_UN` (`JOB_NAME` ASC, `JOB_KEY` ASC) VISIBLE);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_seq` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `UNIQUE_KEY` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY` ASC));




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_execution` (
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  `VERSION` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CREATE_TIME` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `START_TIME` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `END_TIME` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_CODE` VARCHAR(2500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_MESSAGE` VARCHAR(2500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION` VARCHAR(2500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `JOB_INST_EXEC_FK` (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID` ASC) VISIBLE);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_execution_context` (
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `SHORT_CONTEXT` VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
  `SERIALIZED_CONTEXT` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_execution_params` (
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TYPE_CD` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `KEY_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `STRING_VAL` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_VAL` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LONG_VAL` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOUBLE_VAL` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDENTIFYING` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK` (`JOB_EXECUTION_ID` ASC) VISIBLE );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_job_execution_seq` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `UNIQUE_KEY` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY` ASC));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_step_execution` (
  `STEP_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `VERSION` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `STEP_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `START_TIME` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `END_TIME` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMIT_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `READ_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILTER_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `WRITE_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `READ_SKIP_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `WRITE_SKIP_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROLLBACK_COUNT` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_CODE` VARCHAR(2500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_MESSAGE` VARCHAR(2500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `JOB_EXEC_STEP_FK` (`JOB_EXECUTION_ID` ASC) VISIBLE );




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_step_execution_context` (
  `STEP_EXECUTION_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `SHORT_CONTEXT` VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
  `SERIALIZED_CONTEXT` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch_step_execution_seq` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `UNIQUE_KEY` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY` ASC));
  
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 10000 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ);

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 10000 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_JOB_SEQ);
```

Hope this help!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same thing happening to me when moving an anonymized production database to another system. Turns out that the anonymization tool in question [(PostgreSQL Anonymizer)](https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io), has a [bug](https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer/-/issues/213) which results in stripping the commands which set the next value for the exported sequences, so that was the root cause.

This would also cause the ID reported in the stacktrace to be incremented by 1 on with every attempt - since the sequence was erroneously starting at 1, but a lot of previous executions were stored in Spring Batch's tables.

When I sidestepped the issue by setting the next value myself, the problem vanished. In my case, this amounted to:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.batch_job_execution_seq', 6482, true);
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.batch_job_seq', 6482, true);
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.batch_step_execution_seq', 6482, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any option in spring batch so that it starts with next instance id

To answer your question, the "option" you are looking for is the [`RunIdIncrementer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/RunIdIncrementer.html). It will increment a job parameter called "run.id" each time so you will have a new instance on each run.

However, this is not how I would fix the issue (See my comment). You need to check why this duplicate key exception is happening and fix it. Check if you are launching the job with same parameters resulting in the same instance (and even if this happens, you should not have such an exception if the transaction's isolation level of your job repository is correctly configured, I would expect a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` if the last execution succeeded or a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException` if the last execution failed and another one is currently running).